# Could some one explain what does these IComparer, IEnumerable etc stand for

Tags: .net

I am pretty new to .Net. In classes I have seen objects as IComparer, IEnumerable etc.  Could some one explain what does these stand for?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are interfaces.  An interface ensures that an object has certain methods, regardless of it's class.  They are useful when you have code that requires a few common methods, but doesn't need to know all of the details of the class.

`Object()`, `System.Collections.ArrayList` and `System.Collections.Queue` all implement `IEnumerable`.  If you have a function that asks for an `IEnumerable`, you can pass an object of any of these classes to the function, and the function is confident that the object implements all of the IEnumerable members.

Try the following code in a console application.  These three different classes are all acceptable to pass to `PrintAll(items)`.

```
Public Sub PrintAll(items As IEnumerable)
    For Each item In items
        Console.WriteLine(item)
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub Main()
    Dim objects As Object() = {1, 2, 3}
    Dim list As New ArrayList({4, 5, 6})
    Dim queue As New Queue({7, 8, 9})
    PrintAll(objects)
    PrintAll(list)
    PrintAll(queue)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

These are interfaces.  The "I" usually denotes this.  These contain method contracts that any class implementing the specific interface must implement.  In other words, if you have a class that implements IEnumerable then you need to have the methods in your class that are contained in the interface.

Interfaces (and object oriented programming) can get very deep, but that's a broad explanation hopefully simple enough to understand.

Please let me know if I can clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking into the idea of an [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) since these are both interfaces as is evidenced by their [naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bc1fexb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  It would require a potentially long-winded answer to impart complete understanding but the idea is that the interface provides the signatures of methods so that the inheriting class knows which methods to implement.  I realize that was a lot of potentially unfamiliar concepts but think of the interface as a recipe.  You are given the guidelines to create something.  1 C of flour, 1 T of sugar, etc.  When you want to make the item you make sure you can meet the requirements, throw it all together and you have a finished product.  Sorry if this is a terrible analogy, but hope it helps. 
In your case, the names of the interfaces provided by Microsoft give a small idea of what they're intended to represent.  If you inherit [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx), for instance, you end up with a class that can compare two objects.  It's important to note that the type of objects are not necessarily defined by the interface.  It is up to the implementation to dictate the types.  Only the "framework" is provided by the interface.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

ICompare is for comparing stuffs. classes that related to sorting/comparing(obviously) may implement this.

IEnumerable is for collection, listing, linq stuffs.